# Flask in a docker working on Azure but not locally

Tags: azure, docker, flask

Here is my code (app.py) :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World composcan"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=8002)
```

When i use this dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER bussiere "bussiere@composcan.fr"
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "nameserver 80.67.169.12" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" >> /etc/resolv.conf
#RUN echo "dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 80.67.169.12 208.67.222.222" >>  /etc/network/interfaces
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv
RUN export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
RUN export LANG=C.UTF-8
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv --python 3.6
RUN pipenv install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv"]
CMD ["run","python","app.py"]
```

it works on azure perfectly :

```
http://koalabourre.azurewebsites.net/
```

But when i try to run it locally from docker on ubuntu with :

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8002:8002 flask-quickstart
```

i have :

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 101-413-323
```

i can't open it in my browser with localhost:8002

here is the organisation of the project :

[image]

And the docker is here 
https://hub.docker.com/r/dockercompo/koalabourre/

And running app.py outside a container locally works perfectly ...

Comment: I'm genuinely curious : is there some advantage of using `pipenv` in a container context?

Comment: Fix the python version mainly. But i am trying things so don t take my words as rock solide. Also i can test my code without building a container and be sure that the versions of python and modules will be the same even with a system upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be listening on an "external" (docker network) address to forward ports.  Looks to me like your code doesn't quite match the program's output in that regard.

Your code says

```
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=8002)
```

But your output says

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: Nope docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress" and the ip adresse :8002 does not work :/

Comment: you haven't really responded to my point.  You say in your code you're listening on 0.0.0.0, but according to the output you're showing, you're listening on localhost.  Explaining that you can't connect to the docker IP only provides further evidence that you aren't listening on that port.